# custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys

I don't understand why my custom hotkeys aren’t working. The commands work fine on the terminal and my choice of hotkeys do work for other commands ( I tried gedit).

This is what I did, only the first one works:

[image]

[image]

the full command is

```
echo -n  "pause" | nc -U /home/me/.local/share/vlc/vlc.sock
```

IT WORKS ON THE TERMINAL

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning those long commands, I wrote a script that takes options and do the things I want. I then assigned keyboard shortcuts for the script with different options. works like a charm.

btw, I am doing this because the vlc global hotkeys don't work at all -- how did this get past testing??? As a workaround, I configured vlc to take remote commands from a socket of my choice.